# Concatenate strings from different cells into 1 cell

Tags: microsoft-excel

Forgive the ASCII art (art!$?) but how do I get the stuff from C1 & C2 into C3 with some additional text.

```
--------|-------|------------------|
C1      |  C2   |   C3             |
-----------------------------------|
John    |  Doe  |   First Name: C1 |
        |       |   Last  Name: C2 |
-----------------------------------|
```

Comment: BTW how do I handle the new line between First Name and Last Name.

"\n Doesn't Work!"

Comment: Just use Char(10) as the newline character ans make sure you have Wrap text enabled for the cell you use the formula in, otherwise you'll only see a square.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use the concatenate function. You could use something like

`= CONCATENATE("First name: "; C1; CHAR(10); "Last name: "; C2)`

**Edit**: I added CHAR(10) to the formula to create a newline between the 2 fields. However, you have to enable **Wrap text** for the cell.

Comment: I tested this in Excel 2003 and the semi-colon was correct. Trying it out in Excel 2007 works only with using a comma, as you said. This seems odd. Snark also used a semi-colon...

Comment: For Excel 2007 your syntax is wrong - it should be , (comma) rather than ; (semi-colon)

Comment: Odd that they should change this between the 2003 & 2007 versions.

Comment: @ChrisF : difference in the handling of Regional Settings in Excel between the 2003 and 2007 versions? I'm using French settings.

Comment: @Snark could be... I had English at work and Romanian settings at home. It might be an explanation for the difference.

Answer (score 3):

It's in your subject: concatenate! :-)

In C3, use the formula:

```
=concatenate("First Name: ";C1;" Last Name: ";C2)
```

Answer (score 3):

This is what I would use:

```
="First Name: " & C1 & " Last Name: " & C2
```